# ASP.net Gridview Paging doesin't work inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel, paging

Although, questions somehow similar to this have been asked for a number of times, but the question is still unsolved. Here is the question:
I have a `GridView` which is contained in a tab container `AJAX` control  which itself is inside an `UpdatePanel`. `Gridview` works excellent and its corresponding methods are fired accurately, but when I enable `paging`(e.g.) after I click on page 2, the `GridView` hides itself. here is my **PageIndexChanging()** method:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;        
    GridView1.DataBind();
    UpdatePanel2.Update();        
}
```

Why paging causes `GridView` to stop working correctly? What can I do?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1091963.aspx -- Possible solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is that you should refill the dataset which is used to populate the gridview, each time your page index is changed. By this way, you could ensure that in each seperate postback which has been triggered by the gridview page number, results will be populated.

Answer (score 4):

Further research:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295545.aspx

> **Controls that are not compatible with UpdatePanel controls**
>
> The following ASP.NET controls are not compatible with partial-page updates, and are therefore not designed to work inside an UpdatePanel control:
>
> - *GridView and DetailsView controls when their EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks property is set to true. The default is false.*

Answer (score 4):

I just tried that above code. I had same issue and now it is working just fine.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) 
{ 
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;         
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
    //  UpdatePanel2.Update();   <-- Remove this line from your code.
}
```

I have GridView inside update panel. Did you write your event PageIndexChanging in your .aspx file  also?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue , changing the updatepanel property UpdateMode="Conditional" to  UpdateMode="Always" and setting the property ChildrenAsTriggers="true" solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

To do it, you have to re set the datasource in the page index change event. The performance will be lower but that's the way you can make it works.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ;//Set again the datasource
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    UpdatePanel2.Update();
}
```